# What's the equivalent of this import statement using require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, require

I'm trying to convert a few files from using `import` to using `require` to avoid the need for Babel.

One import statement is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

How can I convert it to a `require` statement? I've tried with this:

```
const React, { Component } = require('react');
```

but it says there's an error at the first comma so it doesn't seem to be a valid syntax. Any idea?

Comment: `const React = require('react'), Component = react.Component;`. Linter's might complain about the assignment, but you should get the idea. Listed for brevity.

Comment: This is called Destructuring assignment it's presented in ES6. So to acheave what you want you need this:
const React = require('react');
const Component = React.Component;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you will need to do the following:

Either this syntax:

```
const React = require('react');
const { Component } = require('react').default;
```

Or this syntax:

```
const React = require('react');
const Component = React.Component;
```

For more details: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3049#issuecomment-286205548